# Style the first word of the input placeholder attribute - Possible?

Tags: css, input, css-selectors, placeholder

I want to style the first word of an inputs placeholder attribute.
I can target the placeholder with something like:

```
::-webkit-input-placeholder
```

There are selectors such as first-letter and first-line that can be used together with this, but there seems to be no first-word selector.

I can't wrap this in any tag to style it. Is it possible with javascript/jquery maybe? Or is there a CSS solution that I missed perhaps?

Comment: There's no `first-word` selector in CSS.You'll have to use JS.

Comment: As far as i'm aware, you can't natively. You could possibly make your own using pseudo elements on a `content-editable` div, but would still be hackish

Comment: The only way you could do this with CSS would be on an element-by-element basis using a pseudo element - http://jsfiddle.net/3rror404/r0ntgsx8/1/

Comment: That's a clever trick! This works very well for my case.

However I'm wondering if the placeholder attribute has any semantic meaning attached to it? If so, that would be some drawback with this method.